# buildSrc dir + CustomTask: Method 'doLast` is not implemented

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0

When a `buildSrc` directory exists, Android Studio will erroneously show `Method 'doLast' is not implemented` errors on custom tasks:

To verify the issue I create a new empty Android project in Android Studio (I use V 3.0.1) add a simple custom task to the root `build.gradle` file

```
class Greeting extends DefaultTask {
    String message
    String recipient

    @TaskAction
    void sayGreeting() {
        println "gradle version ${project.getGradle().getGradleVersion()}"
        println "${message}, ${recipient}!"
    }
}

task hello (type : Greeting) {
    group 'Welcome'
    description 'Produces a world greeting'
    message 'Hello'
    recipient 'World'
}
```

This is a very simple example from the gradle-guide [Writing Gradle Tasks](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/#make_the_message_configurable).
The default project uses my gradle V4.1 installation.

When I now refresh the Gradle projects, I can execute the `hello` task and the IDE shows no errors in the `build.gradle` file.

But when you now add a `buildSrc` dir to the project (can be empty) and refresh the Gradle projects again, Android Studio 3.0.1 shows this error: `Method 'doLast' is not implemented`
[image: AS 3.0.1 Error Message]

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix this (without implementing the missing methods)?

UPDATE:

- [Github Project to reproduce the issue](https://github.com/tmtron/as3-gradle-test)
- [Android Studio issue 70015222](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70015222)

Comment: I would not expect that error to show up. What version of Gradle is being used? Does this compile but just show an error in the IDE?

Comment: @mkobit yes, it works, when executed e.g. from the command line. I've edited the question to show the version info.

Comment: I just found out that `buildSrc` dir causes the issue - I've rewritten the question.